# How to exclude a row based on a match between two columns where one column has multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to exclude records based on a match between two column values. One column value is the same for each row (Referring Associate), but the other (Sales Team) can contain multiple values.

In the example below, I do not want to return any Transaction IDs where the Referring ID exists in the Sales Team column. In other words, if the Referring ID matches any of the Sales Team values, then nothing should be returned.

[image: sql question]

I've tried the obvious

```
where Sales Team <> Referring Associate
```

but I end up returning the other 3 records where this condition is false.

**EDIT:**

**Sample Data:**

[image: SampleData]

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output]

**Explanation:**

All of the rows with a red Transaction ID should not be returned in the query results based on a match between Sales Team and Referring Associate.

Comment: Your code has nothing called `Referring ID` so I don't understand the question.

Comment: rather than write a long paragraph of what you want to do, i suggest that you create a Expected Output table instead then explain briefly.   I can't follow your sample data nor want you want to achieve

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the original post to include expected output.

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select referring_associate from tablename 
where referring_associate = sales_team
```

returns all values of `referring_associate` that should be excluded.

So use it in this:

```
select * from tablename 
where 
  referring_associate not in (
    select referring_associate from tablename 
    where referring_associate = sales_team 
  )
```

to return all the other rows.

Comment: Thanks! This is basically the logic that ended up working. I basically just used "TransactionID" NOT IN (The same query returning the records I wanted to exclude).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.transactionid = t.transactionid and
                        t2.salesteam = t.referringassociate
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesTeams.*
FROM dbo.MyTest AS SalesTeams
LEFT JOIN dbo.MyTest ReferringAssociates ON SalesTeams.associateCode = ReferringAssociates.salesTeamCode
WHERE ReferringAssociates.salesTeamCode IS NULL
```